# C# Z3 API calling problems in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, z3

After I imported Z3 in the visual studio 2012, When I try to run a example in my visual studio 2012 , I found that the visual studio cannot find Microsoft.Z3 pakage, after I tried to import again it can find the Microsoft.Z3 but still it cannot find the Config keyword,Can anyboday help me ? or provide me a detailed way to use Z3 in Visual studio 2012? I followed the follwing steps and the above problem occured.

To use the Microsoft Z3 library in your C# projects follow these steps:

```
Go to http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/0a7db466-c2d7-4c51-8246-07e25900c7e7/ and download + install the Z3 package.

Switch to Visual Studio. In the Solution Explorer window right click on the References tree node and select "Add Reference".
In the "Add new reference" dialog navigate to the Microsoft.Z3.dll. You find the Microsoft.Z3.dll under c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin on a Windows x64 bit machine or under c:\Program Files\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin on a Windows x86 machine. To use Parallel Z3 library choose the Microsoft.Z3.dll from the c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin_mt or c:\Program Files\Microsoft Research\Z3-3.2\bin_mt directory.
```

My codes are as following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Z3;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Config cfg = new Config())
            {
                using (Context ctx = new Context(cfg))
                {
                    Term x = ctx.MkConst("x", ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term y = ctx.MkConst("y", ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term zero = ctx.MkConst(0, ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term one = ctx.MkConst(1, ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term three = ctx.MkConst(3, ctx.MkIntSort());
                    Term fml = x > zero & ctx.MkEq(y, x + one) & y < three;
                    ctx.AssertCnstr(fml);
                    Model m = null;
                    LBool is_sat = ctx.CheckAndModel(out m);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(is_sat);

                    if (m != null)
                    {
                        m.Display(Console.Out);
                        m.Dispose();
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using a very outdated version of Z3 (3.2), the latest major release is 4.3.x, please follow the build instructions here to create the library (the unstable branch is probably the best choice):

http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README

then make sure you add the library to the reference path in your solution/project (which it sounds like you've tried to do with the old library), then you can check this example to see how to call the API:

http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#examples/dotnet/Program.cs

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Acutally, I use the easiest way to double click z3-4.1.msi and installed the 4.1 version. Is this OK? If not, can you provide more detailed information about the how to build a latest version, it seems I need to intstall python? because I am toally new to this field and the instruction in README only have several commands I do not know how to use．　THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: On the Z3 webpage you can get a precompiled binary of the unstable branch by going to http://z3.codeplex.com/releases and selecting `planned' on the right. These releases contain the .NET as well as the managed libraries required in the bin folder.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kindly reply. But I am not sure whether I get your point, I tried to download you metioned unstable branch version. I did not find the .NET file. And I found the Microsoft.Z3.dll and libZ3.dll and try to import them into my project and only succeeded import the Microsoft.Z3.dll. And the situation is the same with before. Visual Studio can find the Microsoft.Z3 but cannot find Config,Term such kind of keywords. May I politely ask you to explain why? You know I am a graduate student and totally new about this field.

Comment: Are you following the example in Program.cs (e.g., and have a `using Microsoft.Z3;` import in your file after you've added the reference to the project/solution)?  If you've already followed the example, please post your code and/or project/solution, as it's not clear what the problem is without additional details.

Comment: Also, it would be a good idea to include the specific error message(s) you're receiving.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again.  Yes, I have a "Using Microsoft.Z3" and it seems visual studio can also recognize this. But When I try to write the following:                                        using System;                       
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Z3;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Config cfg = new Config())
            {
                using (Context ctx = new Context(cfg))......  There is a red line under Config,which means

Comment: Visual studio can not recognize it. The errors is all about saying cannot find the Config, Text, and Context and things like that. I will try to reinstall the English version and give you the error inforamtion later. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Now I switch to the 2010 English verison. The problem is still there. The Errors are as following:     Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Config' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 13 20 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: Error 11 The type or namespace name 'Term' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 21 21 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: Error 6 The best overloaded method match for 'Microsoft.Z3.Context.MkConst(Microsoft.Z3.Symbol, Microsoft.Z3.Sort)' has some invalid arguments C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs

Comment: I tried the program in Visual Studio 2013. The Error is    Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Config' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\programming\C#\2013\Z3Demo\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 14 20 ConsoleApplication1

Comment: So, I have personally used Z3 (in different versions 3.1 through 4.3) with VS 2010 and 2013---I don't think this is related to the VS version.  It sounds simply like you have not properly added the Z3 library as a reference to the project/solution, see e.g.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx . Also, unless you have some specific reason to use C# (existing code, etc.), I would recommend the Python API to Z3, as it will probably be easier for you to get running and faster to write whatever you're planning to use.